# Axios is not outputting Console.log but the JSON data is being returned

Tags: api, reactjs, axios

Why can't I grab the JSON  response from an API?  I have this function making an axios POST request to my API.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    axios.post('/api/v1/user_token/',{
      auth: {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      }
    })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.statusText);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

It returns the correct JsonWebToken in the Response body.  But when I try and set a cookie with it or output it to console.log, like `console.log(response.data)` I see nothing in the output.  Relevant images attached.

[JWT returning as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA1p1.png)

[But no output in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xn2o.png)

Comment: have you tried your api using `postman`...

Comment: Seems like that endpoints job is just to return a user token and nothing more. Doesn't seem like it's supposed to return any data.

Comment: I'll try postman because I am seeing the token return. But I don't know how to take it and set it as a Cookie if I can't capture it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the namespace wrong on the response.  Ultimately I stuck was able to log everything out by including `e.preventDefault()` within the function.

```
  handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      axios.post('/api/v1/user_token/',
        {auth: {
          email: this.state.email,
          password: this.state.password
        }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 201) {
          console.log('Authentication failed.' + response.status);
        }
        return response.data;
      })
  }
```